# Prevent getStaticProps in running twice or prevent running when the context.params is empty

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The screenshot below is the problem.

[image: The screenshot below is the problem]

it looks like the get getStaticProps is running twice when there is no data to context params and when there is already data in the context params.

Is there a way to not run wpgraphql query when context params are empty?

below is my file structure

[image]

[productSlug].js

```
import Layout from '@gb-components/layout'
import Product from '@gb-components/product/Product'
import { ProductContextProvider } from '@gb-contexts/ProductContext'
import { getDeliveryInformation } from '@gb-utils/queries/page'
import { getProductPageDataBySlug, getProductReviews, getProductAddOnsByProductId } from '@gb-utils/queries/product'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'


export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [],
        fallback: true,
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {

    const { categorySlug, productSlug } = context.params
    console.log('[productSlug].js getStaticProps', productSlug)

    // Fetch product data from wp site
    const { data } = await getProductPageDataBySlug(productSlug)

    // Fetch the product reviews base on sku in reviews.io api
    const reviews = await getProductReviews(data?.product.sku)

    // Fetch addons data base on product id
    const addons = await getProductAddOnsByProductId(data?.product.productId)

    const deliveryInformation = await getDeliveryInformation()
    return {
        props: { product: data?.product ? { ...data.product, ...reviews.data, ...addons?.data, ...deliveryInformation?.data } : [] }
    }


}

export default function ProductPage(props) {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { product } = props
    // If the page is not yet generated, this will be displayed
    // initially until getStaticProps() finishes running
    if (router.isFallback) {
        return <Layout>
            <div className='container'>
                Loading....
            </div>
        </Layout>
    }

    return (
        <Layout>
            <ProductContextProvider price={product.price} id={product.productId}>
                <Product product={product} />
            </ProductContextProvider>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

I tried adding a check if productSlug is equal to '[productSlug]' and it works but it feels like I shouldn't be doing this because I believe I am doing something wrong that's why [productSlug].js is triggering getStaticProps twice.

```
if ('[productSlug]' === productSlug) {
        //Return nothing since there is nothing in the productSlug variable
        return {
            props: {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the URL of the page you're trying to reach? Are you sure you're using a valid `productSlug` in the URL? It seems you're trying to access the literal value `'[productSlug]'` but that ID doesn't exist in WP.

Comment: domain.com/shop/category-slug/product-slug the id did not exist because it is passing '[productSlug]'. I believe it shouldn't happen because that is the file name of the js file.

Answer (score 1):

```
    export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const { categorySlug, productSlug } = context.params
    console.log('[productSlug].js getStaticProps', productSlug)

    // Fetch product data from wp site
    const { data } = await getProductPageDataBySlug(productSlug)

    // Fetch the product reviews base on sku in reviews.io api
    const reviews = await getProductReviews(data?.product.sku)

    // Fetch addons data base on product id
    const addons = await getProductAddOnsByProductId(data?.product.productId)

    const deliveryInformation = await getDeliveryInformation()
    return {
        props: { product: data?.product ? { ...data.product, ...reviews.data, ...addons?.data, ...deliveryInformation?.data } : [] },revalidate: 10,

    }


}
```

its a major issue in static file regeneration , but next js give the solution already (ISR), need to add revalidate:10 , #here 10 is 10 seconds

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration

Comment: Whats the fix then?

Comment: using ISR u need add revalidate: 10 like this  , here 10 is 10 secs . but i always prefer to use getServerSideProps

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props @jameshwartlopez

Comment: It didn't really work. both adding with revalidate and changing the fallback to blocking did not help fix the issue.